CPU usage is getting increased on NFC usage in android app
On my application I am using NFC to read the NFC card data, After reading CPU usage is getting increased every reading even I kill the activity where I am using NFC. This is happening only in debug mode of app. if I use release mode, there is no issue on app performance. Is it normal behavior or not?
I am already doing disconnectReader(), disableNFCReaderMode() and unRegister() NFC after usage. Here are the functions.
override fun disconnectReader(): Boolean {
        "disconnectReader()".toLog(TAG)
        try {
            tagEventListener?.isoDep?.close()

            nfcManager.disableNFCReaderMode()
            tagEventListener?.isoDep = null
            setCardTappedStatus()
            return true
        } catch (ignored: IOException) {
            "disconnectReader() -> IOException ${ignored.message}".toLog(TAG)
            return false
        } catch (ignored: NullPointerException) {
            "disconnectReader() -> NullPointerException ${ignored.message}".toLog(TAG)
            return true
        }
    }


    fun disableNFCReaderMode() {
        "disableNFCReaderMode(${mActivity.isFinishing})".toLog("NFCManager")
        if (!mActivity.isFinishing) {
             nfcAdapter?.disableReaderMode(mActivity)

            "disableForegroundDispatch():  ${mActivity.javaClass.name}".toLog("NFCManager")
            nfcAdapter?.disableForegroundDispatch(mActivity);
        }
    }

fun unRegister() {
    "unRegister()".toLog(TAG)
    nfcStatusLiveData.removeObservers(activity)
    appSettingLauncher?.unregister()
}

